# Outlook's Personal Folders loading continually

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007, pst

My inbox was reported as full by the ISP. I copied all the messages from the inbox and pasted them into a Personal Folders folder after I had created one (Question number one: Why was it missing?) There was about 1300 messages. They copied and I tried to access the folder. It just says `Loading...` and nothing happens. I tried to restart Outlook and the computer but nothing helped to fix the loading issue. I searched the web for repairing the datafile and tried to do it with program called `SCANPST.EXE`, found in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12`. It found seven folders and the 1300 messages in the file. Second question: where were the seven folders got from?

So it seems all my messages are in the pst file but Outlook won't load them. How do I fix it?

Comment: Was this POP3 or IMAP? Did you alrady have a .pst file or an .ost? Or neither?

Comment: It was an IMAP account. What do you mean by having already a .pst file? If you mean the account, yes, if the personal folders file, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with an add-in. I removed it and it started to work. The remove process was needed to be done safe mode because otherwise Outlook crashed.

The problematic add-in was [Microsoft's SMS add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5887).

Answer (score 0):

You asked why your .PST file was it missing - the answer is because you had an IMAP - all the data is stored on the server.

Copying from the inbox to a .PST file has moved your emails from your 'main account'. We need to just attach your new .PST file as a data file.

These instructions are for Oultook 2010 but should be very simlar: Open File (or Windows logo at top left of Oultook) -> Account settings -> Account Settings. Now click the Data files tab.  Click Add - browse for your .pst file and then click OK. This will have added to Outlook (but this remains an offline version).

Comment: I meant the entry exists in Outlook, but it's not accessible. It says "Loading..."

Comment: Open task manager. See how many agents.exe are running. Close all and then try. If this helps I will post a fix.

Comment: I wasn't able to find such process. I started Outlook in safe mode (not sure what had happened, but it said something was wrong and I selected to start in safe mode) and then I was able to access the mails immediately.

Comment: I posted the correct solution which was causing the problems in my case.