# Outlook stopped working after updating to Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

I downloaded Windows 8 update from Microsoft's site and installed it. Everything works perfectly except Outlook.

Sometimes receiving messages doesn't work for whatever reason. Now the problem is sending and replying. Before these two worked but after receiving messages started to work, these problems have occurred.

When I try to press New to create a new email, I get the following error message

```
Cannot create the e-mail message because a data file to send and receive messages cannot be found. To add a data file, such as a personal folder file, double click the Mail icon in Windows Control.
```

When I try to reply a message, I get the following one

```
The operation failed. An object could not be found.
```

After the update Outlook worked ok. I've had [other problems](https://superuser.com/questions/508170/outlooks-personal-folders-loading-continually) with Outlook too.

Comment: Sounds like your Office installation is corrupt I would reinstall it.

Comment: I used the repair option on the disk. I think it did something, because it asked me to reboot and now it says `The operation cannot be performed because the object has been deleted" when trying to reply. When creating a new email, the same error occurs. Edit. After trying to click reply again, the same error occurs as in the start post.

Comment: @MikkoP try to uninstall and then re-install the Office pack, also see if change the default browser to IE makes any difference.